# Interpolate (upsample) non-equispaced timeseries into equispaced with Pandas version 18.0rc1

Tags: python, pandas

I want to interpolate (upscale) nonequispaced time-series to obtain equispaced time-series.

Currently I am doing it in following way:

1. take original timeseries.
2. create new timeseries with  NaN values at each 30 seconds intervals ( using resample('30S').asfreq() )
3. concat original timeseries and new timeseries
4. sort the timeseries to restore order of times (This I do not like - sorting has complexity of O = n log(n) )
5. interpolate
6. remove original points from the timeseries

is there a more simple way with Pandas version 18.0rc1? like in matlab you have original timeseries and you pass new times as a parameter to the interpolate() function to receive values at desired times.

I remark that times of original timeseries might not be be a subset of the times of desired timeseries.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = [271238, 329285, 50, 260260, 263711]
timestamps = pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-04 08:29:4',
                             '2015-01-04 08:37:05',
                             '2015-01-04 08:41:07',
                             '2015-01-04 08:43:05',
                             '2015-01-04 08:49:05'])

ts = pd.Series(values, index=timestamps)
ts
ts[ts==-1] = np.nan
newFreq=ts.resample('60S').asfreq()

new=pd.concat([ts,newFreq]).sort_index()
new=new.interpolate(method='time')

ts.plot(marker='o')
new.plot(marker='+',markersize=15)

new[newFreq.index].plot(marker='.')

lines, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
labels = ['original values (nonequispaced)', 'original + interpolated at new frequency (nonequispaced)', 'interpolated values without original values (equispaced!)']
plt.legend(lines, labels, loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There have been several requests for a simpler way to interpolate at desired values (I'll edit in links later, but search the issue tracker for interpolate issues). So in the future there will be an easier way.

For now you can write the option a bit more cleanly as

```
In [9]: (ts.reindex(ts.index | newFreq.index)
           .interpolate(method='time')
           .loc[newFreq.index])
Out[9]:
2015-01-04 08:29:00              NaN
2015-01-04 08:30:00    277996.070686
2015-01-04 08:31:00    285236.860707
2015-01-04 08:32:00    292477.650728
2015-01-04 08:33:00    299718.440748
                           ...
2015-01-04 08:45:00    261362.402778
2015-01-04 08:46:00    261937.569444
2015-01-04 08:47:00    262512.736111
2015-01-04 08:48:00    263087.902778
2015-01-04 08:49:00    263663.069444
Freq: 60S, dtype: float64
```

This still involves all the steps you listed above, but the unioning of the indexes is cleaner than concating and dropping.